# get the value with the first letter of database

Tags: php, letter

In my mysql database I have table 'class' with column 'classname' contain : `Andree,adele,Beta,Alfa`

How can I get all the names in 'classname' whose first letter is 'a' or 'A' by php code ?
I tried many ways to do this but they did not give the correct result

Comment: RTLM? http://php.net/substr  But don't do filtering in PHP. you don't buy up an entire store's inventory, take it home, then throw everything away just because you only wanted 1 candy bar.

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT classname FROM class WHERE classname LIKE 'a%'`

You'll use a query similar to this somewhere in your PHP code... We'd need a sample of your PHP to give you anything more than that.

Comment: alternatively, `WHERE LEFT(classname, 1) = 'a'`.

Answer (score 1):

See [substr](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.substr.php) on the php docs.

```
$firstLetter = substr($string, 0, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT classname FROM `class` WHERE classname LIKE 'a%'");
```

note that LIKE is case-insensitive.

Comment: Just an FYI, `mysql_query()` should no longer be used... Documentation states "Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used."